# Refreshing prerendered pages in angular without rebuilding

Tags: angular, angular-universal, prerender

My project is Angular v17 and I'm using the prerender feature on my dynamic pages. It's important for me that these pages content stay updated atleast 3-4 times each day. Is there any command or any way I can refresh the prerendered pages and prerender them again without restarting my Angular container and rebuilding it ?

Comment: Prerendering is for static pages. If you are dynamically updating a page then it's no longer acting in such a static format. If the data of your desired pages are not required in the prerendered versions you can just fetch them from the browser and update them accordingly

Comment: @RadowanMahmudRedoy But prerender performance is much better than SSR so I need my pages to be prerendered and updated once a day for example, I can do that with a rebuilding the project each time but that doesn't feel right.

Comment: @RadowanMahmudRedoy for instance you could need to prerender pages that can be modified using a CMS. In this case, if the pages are not modified very often, it makes sense to prerender them, and sometimes prerender a page if you know that the content has changed (for instance using a webhook triggered by the CMS)

Comment: @jbgt if you are using something like a cms or a webhook, your page is no longer static. It becomes a dynamic page. So, you can run it as a normal page.  Prerendering is a strategy where you will create the pages early that is at the time of build.  

You can skip the dynamic portion and prerender the skeleton of the page and fetch the data from the browser, but again that is not proper server-side rendering

Comment: @BehnamAminazad yes. I have also faced similar situations. But as you said rebuilding every time there is a change is not a good option. Let me know If you have found any alternatives but so far SSR is the solution afaik